# В чем разница между информационной системой и информационным ресурсом?

Tags: веб-сервер

Я - юрист в социально-экономической сфере по законодательству Республики Беларусь. Пишу магистерскую диссертацию об образовательных веб-порталах и дистанционных образовательных технологиях. Наше законодательство обязывает проводить государственную регистрацию информационных систем и информационных ресурсов, для чего ведется специальный регистр: http://www.ipps.by:9087/apex/f?p=124:1:0::NO:::

Вопрос: "В чем разница между понятиями "информационная система" и "информационный ресурс" на практике? Как пояснить пользователю веб-сайта, размещенного в сети Интернет, что то, что он видит это является "информационной системой", а вот это - "Информационным ресурсом"?

Спасибо.

Comment: Процитировав соответствующие определения из закона?

Comment: На бытовом уровне можно так. Книги в библиотеке - это информационный ресурс, а каталожная система библиотеки поиска книг и их выдачи читателям - это информационная система. Тут важно отметить, что пользователь системы в ходе ее использования добавляет/изменяет информацию в этой системе.