# В чем отличие Автоматизированной системы от информационного ресурса?

Tags: 1с, юридические-аспекты

На примере 1С. Есть платформа 8.3 к примеру, есть АС 1С Предприятие, есть база mysql, есть клиент.
Что здесь что?
На примере вот этого ответа ([В чем разница между информационной системой и информационным ресурсом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740198/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc))

Что библиотека это АС, а книги в ней это инф. ресурс выходит что таблички, заполняемые пользователями (данные в них) это и есть ИР? Если судить по законодательству РФ?

Answer (score 0):

По-простому (на мой взгляд) информация которой обмениваются люди - является ИР.
А инфраструктура хранящая и обрабатывающая информацию - является информационной системой

Статья 4. Основы правового режима информационных ресурсов

1. Информационные ресурсы являются объектами отношений физических, юридических лиц, государства, составляют информационные ресурсы России и защищаются законом наряду с другими ресурсами.

см: http://ivo.garant.ru/#/document/10103678/paragraph/45:0